# UPDATE NULL of a column matching the ID in the same table

Tags: mysql, join, insert-update, isnull, ifnull

I'm working on housing data with several columns. In the cleaning process, I noticed that in the column  'PropertyAddress' are a few Null, and I want to confirm if those Null could be matched with the ParcelID. So, I wrote the following query to confirm the previous affirmation with the result shown below the query.

```
SELECT a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b .ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress
FROM nashville_housing a
JOIN nashville_housing b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

| ParcelID | PropertyAddress | ParcelID | PropertyAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 092 13 0 322.00 | NULL | 092 13 0 322.00 | 237 37TH AVE N, NASHVILLE |
| 043 04 0 014.00 | NULL | 043 04 0 014.00 | 112 HILLER DR, OLD HICKORY |
| 026 05 0 017.00 | NULL | 026 05 0 017.00 | 208 EAST AVE, GOODLETTSVILLE |
| 042 13 0 075.00 | NULL | 042 13 0 075.00 | 222 FOXBORO DR, MADISON |

After confirming that I could use ParcelID to change the Nulls with the correct PropertyAddress, I wrote the UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE nashville_housing
SET PropertyAddress = ( 
SELECT a.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, b .ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress
FROM nashville_housing a
JOIN nashville_housing b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null);
```

and give the error 'Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

So, I rewrite the query to:

```
UPDATE a
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null;
```

and give the error 'Error Code: 1146. Table 'nasville_housing.a' doesn't exist'

Finally, I wrote:

```
UPDATE a
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress) in (
SELECT a.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, b .ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress
FROM nashville_housing a
JOIN nashville_housing b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null);
```

but give the error 'Error Code: 1146. Table 'nasville_housing.a' doesn't exist'

I appreciate the support anyone can give me.

Comment: Why would you try and put these 4 columns into the Address column `a.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, b .ParcelID, .PropertyAddress` You have you sanity check your code, specially when the error message is so clear about the issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was not trying to ```... put these 4 columns into the Address column...```. But, because I'm new in these and still learning basic things I tried all the things that passed for my mind, and what I found on the internet.

Comment: Your error `'Error Code: 1146. Table 'nasville_housing.a' doesn't exist'` tells you that you forgot the `h`  in the table name `nashville_housing`

Comment: Thanks @Kendle, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can UPDATE using JOIN: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

```
UPDATE nashville_housing a
LEFT JOIN nashville_housing b ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID 
AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID 
SET a.PropertyAddress = b.PropertyAddress 
WHERE
    a.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```

Comment: RiggsFolly :   is `a.PropertyAddress ISN NULL;` a special syntax or did you mean `IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: It was a typing error. I mean IS NOT NULL